# why the blocking get() is too slow and asynchronous method chaining is not when taking the lower level implementation into consideration?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, synchronous

The following program

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
Future<Result> future = service.submit(firstTask);
Result result = future.get();
service.execute(() -> use(result));
```

could be executed and get the correct result, but the performance is probably badly affected by the *blocking* `get()`

This can be resolved by using the *asynchronous* `CompletableFuture`.

*Question*: why the *blocking* `get()` is too slow and *asynchronous method chaining* is not when taking the lower level implementation into consideration? for instance, is it because the implementation of *blocking* `get()` or `join()` etc. (probably by means of `wait()` in the `Object`) will force the *thread* to *BLOCKED* or *WAITING* state, and what about the *asynchronous* methods? what on earth are the root reasons for *blocking* `get()` or `join` to be that slow and *asynchronous methods* is usually fast?

Comment: Asynchronous operations are not faster. Waiting for a result takes at least as long as the computation of the result. Not waiting for the result takes less time. That shouldn’t come as a surprise.

Comment: But for instance, in the program above, waiting is compulsory, in this case is asynchronous method on `CompletableFuture` such as `thenRunAsynch` still faster than the `get`?

Comment: From which point to which point are you measuring?

Comment: by the total execution time

Comment: Then, there is no significant difference. Mind that when a thread spawns an asynchronous operation, it’s asynchronous from the initiating thread’s perspective, but for the worker thread executing the operation, it’s an ordinary synchronous. The advantage of asynchronous operations is that the initiating thread can do something else in the meantime. When you perform a blocking `get` or `join` you’re not only giving up that advantage, you then have two threads incapable of doing anything else. So when blocking immediately after submitting, it will be worse than a simple synchronous execution.

Comment: @Holger thanks a lot for the explanation. So esp. in case the amount of threads is less than the amount of CPU cores the blocking will cause some unutilized idle cores?

Comment: The effect of a waiting thread depends on the scenario you want to compare with, i.e. what you’d do with that thread if you did not let wait. When you consider a thread pool with a filled work queue, things get more complicated. For an ordinary pool and future, blocking a worker thread with a wait operation reduces parallelness. For `ForkJoinPool` and `CompletableFuture`, the framework will detect when you wait for a result and do either, utilize the thread for other work in-between or start a compensation thread. Still, both is more expensive than chaining a dependent action.

Comment: What is the "chaining a dependent action"?

Comment: The `thenRunAsynch` you already mentioned. Or `thenApply`, `thenCompose`, etc.